# What chars cannot be removed from keywords in vim

Tags: vim

If I try `set iskeyword-=a` 'a' remains part of a word. In other words, it remains part of the list of keywords. So, it seems some chars cannot be removed from the list of keywords. I was wondering what the rules are concerning which chars can be removed from the keyword list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default value of `'iskeyword'` is a comma-separated list. On unix-like systems, it is:

```
@,48-57,_,192-255
```

`:set iskeyword-=a` means "remove item `a` from that list" but there is no item `a`, here, so that command does nothing.

On the other hand,

```
:set iskeyword-=_
```

would remove the underscore because `_` is an item of that list.

In this option, `@` is a shortcut for most alphabetical characters so there is nothing to remove explicitly from that list if you only want to remove character `a`.

To remove a specific alphabetical character, you are supposed to use this notation:

```
:set iskeyword+=^a
```

**But that doesn't sound like a very good idea as it will probably break many things, beginning with syntax highlighting.**

See `:help 'iskeyword'` and `:help 'isfname'` for a comprehensive explanation of the value.